# How to get iOS bundle id for Firebase?

Tags: ios, windows, firebase, react-native, bundle-identifier

I am trying to connect the Firebase project to my current react-native app (Windows 10 OS).
I am following steps from https://rnfirebase.io/.

However when I try to add iso app, I need the iOS bundle ID of the project, but I seem not to find it.

The only thing I find, after 2 hours of research on Google, is that the `info.plist` suppose to have this data but mine got only this:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that string is set in `project.pbxproj`. You can find it by global searching `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER`.

Or you can open the Xcode by opening `.xcworkspace` file and

1. select the top project item in the project navigator at the left.
2. select TARGETS -> General.
3. Bundle Identifier is found under Identity.

======EDIT

the  ${PRODUCT_NAME: rfc1034identifier} is a formatted string with `product_name`.

> rfc1034Identifier: Replaces any non-rfc1034 identifier characters with a hyphen (-).

BTW, you should set one yourself.
FYI, using `react-native-rename`

Comment: Thaks for your reply. I am working on WIndows OS, so i dont have Xcode at all. However i have done the global search and th only things that were found, did not incldue the ID, this is the screenshot https://ibb.co/j82HQ6j

Comment: oh, that means that is a fresh project. edited my ans.

Comment: Thanks for this. I feel stupid to ask more, but could you please explain then what exactly should i use as a bundle ID for firebase? Because is till dont get :(

Comment: `org.reactjs.native.example.UltraCouples`, but you should change it. The easiest way is to use the react-native-rename packacge